# Show that set $A=${$x \in \mathbb{Q} :-1<x<1$} is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ but not closed in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, rational-numbers

> Show that set $A=${$x \in \mathbb{Q} :-1<x<1$} is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ but not closed in $\mathbb{Q}$

The set $A$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ as we take any point $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $p \in A$ then we can choose an $ \epsilon >0$  then $p - \epsilon >-1$ and $p + \epsilon <1$,then we see that $ \epsilon  < 1$, we can actually get a neighborhood such that set is open.

We see that $1$ is also a limit point of $A$ but $1$ doesn't belong to the set so $(A)^{'} \ne A$ hence these is not closed . Is this attempt correct

Comment: Writing $A = (-1,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is another way to see that $A$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: As a subset $E$ is open in $Y$ if there exists an open set $G$ then , $E=Y \cap G$

Comment: Please include the actual question in the question body instead of only in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Another way to look at it is: $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if there is a closed set $F$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $F \cap \mathbb{Q} = A$. So in particular, $A \subseteq F$ and hence the closure of $A$ is a subset of $F$. But what is the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$? And then what is $\bar{A} \cap \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: There is something in the background that might be worth mentioning, depending on how the topology on $\mathbb Q$ is defined, and that is that the topology generated by the restriction of a metric is the same as the relative topology.